# Image width using Bootstrap does not size properly

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

using bootstrap 3.

I have 4 img elements.

2 images across
2 images down

Total of 4 images.

This is my markup:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="row" id="row1">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="" id="img1" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="" id="img2" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="Div1">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="" id="img3" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="" id="img4" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Trouble is that there is a gap in the middle.
When I view the element using Chrome there are no margins or paddings automatically set by Bootstrap.

What should I do/use?

This is the screenshot (this is a mobile browser)

[image]

Comment: You could tighten the gutter... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077931/three-inputs-in-a-row-bootstrap-3/26078033#26078033

Comment: You could also try the `.thumbnail` class to evenly space them http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Comment: Hi, for some reaon tight-gutter had no affect an dthe .thumbnail class did not make a difference either - but it did give a nice hote border effect :)

Comment: Do you have any styling on `#row1` and `#Div1`?

Comment: @tim Hi, no it does not but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking it may be the width of your images. Depending on the width of your page, large images will fill the col and tighten up the gutter between them

```
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" id="img1" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" id="img2" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="Div1">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" id="img3" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" id="img4" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

smaller image will leave a gap

```
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img1" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img2" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="Div1">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img3" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="img4" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

See it in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timgavin/nmwuyhad/

Comment: Hi, my images are designed for desktop browser I am using the "img-responsive" to auo-scale my images for the mobile - which is does.

Answer (score 0):

I added this styling to ensure padding and margin is zero and it worked:

```
 <div id="col1" class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
```

Comment: that's what I had in my first comment :)